# Customized Visual Studio HTML Colors Not Recognized

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have imported a color theme to Visual Studio. Most colors are what they should be, but there are a few that revert back to the default color several seconds after Visual Studio first launches.

Going into Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors, the font color matches the theme color, so the setting is correct. Something is forcing the font color back to the default, and I don't know what else could affect that setting.

The font colors I have noticed that revert back to the default are:
HTML Attribute Name
HTML Attribute Value
HTML Element Name
HTML Server-Side Script

The pattern repeats when Visual Studio is restarted. Initially, the font colors are the theme colors, then after several seconds they are changed to the default font colors.

What is causing a select few font colors to revert to the default?